# Hiring a Private Investigating Agency

Tags: family-tree

If I want to research about my ancestors however I don't have the time or the relevant data on how to do so is it possible to hire someone to do this task? If yes how safe is it and is it recommended by people. Also what might be some good agencies or organisations to do so?

In particular, [Possibility of tracing my great grandfather's wife's homeland](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15620/10504) addresses the things I want to research about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, yes, it is possible to employ professional genealogists to carry out research on your behalf.  A lot of people do it, especially when they hit 'brick walls' in their research or need copies of records held in archives that they cannot access, and many - perhaps most - are very happy with the results they get.

You should be aware that employing professional genealogists can be expensive.  For this reason, it is important to ensure that you provide them with all the information that you have (together with copies of any documents etc.) ***right at the start of the process***.  Otherwise you might find that you are paying them to find out what you already know!

My advice would be to have the research carried out in agreed stages, and to **always agree a quote for the expected cost of each stage in advance**!

The Society of Genealogists have produced a guide with hints and tips for [Employing a Professional Genealogist](http://www.sog.org.uk/learn/education-sub-page-for-testing-navigation/hints-tips-six-employing-a-professional-genealogist).  While written with researchers in the UK in mind, many of these tips are applicable more widely.

---

Obviously, you are going to want to check that the person you will be employing to carry out your research is competent before you hand over any money.  Many countries have certifying bodies and/or professional bodies that represent professional genealogists and researchers.  For example,:

In the UK

- [Association of Genealogists & Researchers in Archives](https://www.agra.org.uk/memberbrowse) (AGRA)

In the USA (and also internationally)

- [Association of Professional Genealogists](https://www.apgen.org/directory/search.html?type=location&new_search=true) APG

In Australia & New Zealand

- [Australasian Association of Genealogists and Record Agents Inc](https://www.aagra.asn.au/) (AAGRA)

---

Unfortunately, as far as I can see, there doesn't appear to be an equivalent body in India, and (at the moment) India isn't one of the countries of residence listed on the search page of the APG website.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the answer. Is it possible to hire one in UK or other such countries having an organisation to help me?

Comment: There are certainly some professional UK agencies with AGRA certification that can do research in India and elsewhere. I did a quick Google search using the terms `"professional" "genealogical research" "india"` and got a few hits that appear promising.  Good luck with your research.

Comment: thanks a lot for the heads up